# How can I extract frames from videos (using DirectShow)?

Tags: c++, windows, video, directshow

I have to extract the frames from any video file that can be played using the standard windows media player into separate images. Can you provide me some info on how to proceed, what documentation/books to read, etc?

The language is C/C++.

Also, don't recommend any solution which involves GPL code, the software I have to work on is proprietary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can recommend you the following excellent example on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/VideoImageGrabber.aspx). It shows you how to process frames from a camera source or an avi file.

Answer (score 1):

You may just add a [`SampleGrabber`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd407288(VS.85).aspx) filter to your graph, and save the images to the disk in a callback function as they pass down the graph.